# Disable top sites from Ubuntu Touch's default browser

Tags: ubuntu-touch, default-browser

Is it possible to disable the top sites in Ubuntu Touch's default browser when opening a new tab?

So far the only way I've found is by removing the whole browser history, but that is not a solution because I need the history.

Answer (score 0):

You can select individual sites from "Top Sites" by touching and dragging to the right - a trashcan icon will appear and allow you to delete selected sites.

Otherwise I haven't seen the option to change the new tab page.

Comment: This must be from the beta versions, because there's no such functionality in 14.10. Trouble is that it still won't help because when I delete one top site another one will take its place, and the tab still won't be completely blank...